# Evaluate formula with javascript + jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

ok, I have 3 input text

```
<input type="text" data-operand="rate">
<input type="text" data-operand="qty">
<input type="text" data-operation="rate*qty">
```

I have a string of formula like

```
rate*qty
```

which i got from input attribute 'data-operation'

now I want to make function like

```
function(formula) { ... }
```

which gives me result

and I want to do something like this.

```
$('input[data-operand="rate"]').val() * $('input[data-operand="qty"]').val()
```

using jquery javascript library

Comment: your .val() values may be needed to be converted to an integer. Also how does your markup look like? is there only one input element that has the data-operand value of rate and qty?

Comment: thank you but thats not the problem
I have function like calculate
which passes the parameter formula in string

Comment: @voigtan: * coerces to a number, no need to get explicit and .val() returns a single value each time, not an array.

Comment: you could use eval() or many switch cases, depending on your app's needs.

Comment: @RushabhJoshi Are you trying to get the `data-operand` depending on the formula ? is that your question ?

Comment: Yes navin, if I set data-operation string, my function automatically execute the operation with appropriate data-operand value in input text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to apply a dynamic formula to dynamic values.

It's the purpose of the `eval()` function, or best the `Function` constructor.
For example:

```
var formulae = new Function('a', 'b', $('[data-operation]').data('opearation'));

function compute() {
  var args = [
    +$('[data-operand=rate]').val(), 
    +$('[data-operand=qty]').val()
  ];
  $('#result').text(formulae.apply({}, args));
}

compute();
$('input').keyup(compute);
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4PMU/2/)

There may be more generic way to declare your arguments (the names and order are significative inside the function constructor).

*** EDIT ***

If you want to deal with changing number of formulae arguments, you will have difficulties to specify them to the Function constructor.
In Javascript, it's very difficult to dynamically invoke a constructor.

But we can use a special property of dynamic functions. See this blue frame in the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function): global variables are accessible.

What you can do is to set your formula's arguments in the global scope (window), and do not specify them as constructor argument.

I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4PMU/2/)
this way. All you have is to add another input, and update your formula.

Comment: Yeah it helped me, but sometimes(every time) I have more than 2 text input which increase the complexity of my project so I just want to pass formula like `x+y(a*b/100)` and my input field value set the result

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is, but based on your answer, you either want to actually perform the arithmetic operation, or you want it to serve as a placeholder.

To perform the math, you may need to convert what you get back from .val() into a number. If you're looking for an integer, then use parseInt(). If you're looking for a floating point number (say you're calculating money amounts), then start with parseFloat and clean it up from there.

On the other hand, if you're looking to create a function for values to be dropped into, then set those as parameters for the function and pass in arguments when you call it, like:

```
function volumeCalc(rate, qty) { var totalVol = (rate * qty); return totalVol; }
```